# Use case expression with temp table in where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

`StatusId` is a comma separated string. If `StatusId` is '0' then all rows should be fetched. Otherwise I need to join with temp table `#StatusIdVal` and relevant records should only be fetched.

```
CREATE Procedure TestSchema.GetDetails
(
    @StatusId   Varchar(MAX)
)
As
Begin
SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TempStatusVal') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
      DROP TABLE #TempStatusVal
    END

    Create Table #TempStatusVal (StatusId Int Primary Key)

    Insert into #TempStatusVal (StatusId)
    SELECT Distinct ITEMS FROM TestSchema.SPLIT(@StatusId, ',')

    Select  *
    From TestSchema.tblDetails TD with (NoLock)
    Where TD.StatusId In (Select Case When @StatusId = '0' Then TD.StatusId Else (Select StatusId From #TempStatusVal) End)

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TempStatusVal') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
      DROP TABLE #TempStatusVal
    END

SET NOCOUNT OFF
End
GO
```

I can understand that if `#TempStatusVal` have more than one records returning an exception

> subquery return more than 1 value this is not permitted

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Check the place where you have applied case statement. It is incorrect. Please check out my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to `WHERE` clause like this

```
WHERE @StatusId = '0'
OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #TempStatusVal WHERE TD.StatusId = StatusId)
```

Comment: i am getting same exception mentioned in question.

Comment: @vinothkumar - show how you are using this code. It shouldn't raise that error so presumably you have applied it incorrectly

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes i added exactly in one part of condition. Missed in another condition. It works fine.

Comment: Happy to Help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it in this way

```
Select  *
From TestSchema.tblDetails TD with (NoLock)
Where @StatusId = '0' or TD.StatusId In (Select t.StatusId From #TempStatusVal t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making it complex add one more query to return data when **@StatusId <> '0'**

```
CREATE Procedure TestSchema.GetDetails
(
    @StatusId   Varchar(MAX)
)
As
Begin
SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TempStatusVal') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
      DROP TABLE #TempStatusVal
    END

    Create Table #TempStatusVal (StatusId Int Primary Key)

    Insert into #TempStatusVal (StatusId)
    SELECT Distinct ITEMS FROM TestSchema.SPLIT(@StatusId, ',')

    --Select  *
    --From TestSchema.tblDetails TD with (NoLock)
    --Where TD.StatusId In (Select Case When @StatusId = '0' Then TD.StatusId Else (Select StatusId From #TempStatusVal) End)

    Select  TD.StatusId
    From TestSchema.tblDetails TD with (NoLock)
    Where @StatusId = '0'

    union all

    Select  TD.StatusId
    From #TempStatusVal TD with (NoLock)
    Where @StatusId <> '0'


    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TempStatusVal') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
      DROP TABLE #TempStatusVal
    END

SET NOCOUNT OFF
End
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE Procedure TestSchema.GetDetails
(
    @StatusId   Varchar(MAX)
)
As
Begin
SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TempStatusVal') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
      DROP TABLE #TempStatusVal
    END

    Create Table #TempStatusVal (StatusId Int Primary Key)

    Insert into #TempStatusVal (StatusId)
    SELECT Distinct ITEMS FROM TestSchema.SPLIT(@StatusId, ',')

    Select  *
    From TestSchema.tblDetails TD with (NoLock)
    Where TD.StatusId In (
    Select Case @StatusId   When  '0' Then TD.StatusId Else  StatusId  End
    From #TempStatusVal
    )

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TempStatusVal') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
      DROP TABLE #TempStatusVal
    END

SET NOCOUNT OFF
End
GO
```